# How do I diagonalize a matrix quickly in C++?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, armadillo, diagonal

I don't know which library to choose (for windows): LAPACK++, Armadillo, IT++, Eigen, or maybe something else?

All I need to do is to check if a big (about 10,000*10,000) matrix is diagonalizable, and if so, to get the diagonal and the invertible matrix such that D=(P^(-1))*A*P. This has to be done as fast as possible. I have no idea which library to use.

Also, I'll be happy to know in general what are the pros and cons of each of these libraries.

Comment: I don't think it's faster and I have a whole program in c++ so it won't be so convenient. Is it faster? Thanks!

Comment: MatLab is written in C++ and I am pretty sure the guys who worked on it did their best to make it fast. Furthermore, they might have special built in functions for that, so the script might take just a couple of lines. Just google it, there is a lot of info on that.

Comment: OK thanks! I just thought it would be slower because there is no compiler. Do you know how to use matlab in C++?

Comment: No clue. But why use it in C++? It also has it's own compiler.

Comment: What do you mean? I have already written most of the program in C++. And BTW it is faster in C++ because of the compiler (I tried to write it in matlab at first and it took much longer).

Comment: Diagonalize a matrix is easy: no more than 5-6 lines. I think you may implement it yourself without troubles.
For optimization:
1) use (?:) instead of if-then branches if possible. 2) Avoid index-access (matrix[i]), it's much better to use pointer and increment it.etc.

Comment: 5-6 lines? I don't see how that can be done. If you can write it I will be grateful.

Comment: @EllaShar That entire comment was nonsense, `?:` is exactly the same as if-else and pointer arithmetic is exactly the same as `[]`. The CPU doesn't care about which punctuation notation is in the source code.

Comment: Is this 10000x10000 matrix really actually dense?

Answer (score 4):

This may be a rather vague answer, since I don't know what exact problem you're up against, but it is very often the case that you don't actually need all that information, i.e. you only care about a matrix' eigenvalues with the most energy; and as for the rest - does it really matter if you have 0.001 as an eigenvalue (diagonalizable matrix) or 0.000 (non-diagonalizable)? For many real-world (and even theoretical) applications, the answer is 'not really'.

So, my suggestion is that you gain *speed* by giving up on the *accuracy* or *granularity* of the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take this with a grain of salt, but [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark) are some benchmarks published by the developers of Eigen. I have never used any other linear algebra library besides Eigen, but your needs may differ from mine.

Answer (score -3):

As far as finding the determinant goes, there are a number of different implementations that you can use. One is to use Gaussian Elimination to create an upper/lower triangular matrix - this is beneficial in that you then just have to multiply on the diagonal to get the determinant. If any row or any column ends up zeroing out as a result, you will have a determinant of 0 and the matrix will not have an inverse. You could actually use this method and augmenting the matrix with an identity matrix and performing a full Gauss-Jordan elimination and turning the original matrix into an identity matrix as seen at http://www.mathportal.org/linear-algebra/matrices/gauss-jordan.php .

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how that answers my question, please clarify.