# How to make a given matrix diagonally dominant in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, diagonal

Now for the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods to work the matrix needs to be diagonally dominant. Any help would be appreciated.
Its different than making a matrix diagonal. //Because of the downvotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagonalize a matrix quickly in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599284/how-do-i-diagonalize-a-matrix-quickly-in-c)

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: @ScottHunter What code?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Exactly my point.

Comment: @ScottHunter Ah, point taken

Comment: @ArnavBorborah now that you've taken it, there's no point to answer to.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi What are you implying, (irrelevantly)

Comment: @ArnavBorborah sorry, I might have forgotten a "large grin" emoticon - never mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing you can do. If matrix don't satisfy conditions of some method, use other methods that can be applied to this matrix.

Remember, in such bad cases you can use Gauss Elimination to solve SLAE.